# Changing port of WAMP, gives Unable to connect on Windows XP

Tags: windows

On Windows 7 everything works smoothly, but on Windows XP machine I get Unable to connect.

```
Listen 1231

NameVirtualHost *:1231

<VirtualHost *:1231>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\test\public"
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried disabling Firewall, but nothing. Hope someone will help. Thanks.

EDIT: I am typing `localhost:1231` in a Browser

I did restarted server. I am not on a virtual machine.

Comment: What URL are you using to connect? Did you restart the server? Are you 100% sure the firewall is disabled? Are you on a virtual machine with this?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the server is running? Is the service showing as "Running" in the services list?

Comment: I am 100% sure that I did disabled the firewall. And service is running.

Comment: Hmm, strange. ---

Comment: When I have two ports listening (eg 80 and 1231), its redirect to port 80.

Comment: you have other server than wamp , xampp perhaps or visual studio ?

Comment: Its a fresh copy of Windows XP, with only WAMP on it.

Comment: remove WAMP and install it again

Comment: I done that already.

Comment: its really strange , can you try XAMPP 
also check other things like skype if its running , if so stop it

Comment: `netstat -nao | findstr :1231`?

Comment: Try a higher port like 8080. Restart WAMP and test.